# Error ORA-12560 TNS:protocol adapter error

Tags: database, oracle, adapter, ora-12560

I just Installed Oracle DB g11 whenever I want to login to scott/tiger database, It gives me ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error.
But there's a weird thing. Now, alot of people say that I have to start the OracleService from services in my PC. But, I can't find it there. I would be thankful if you helped me. Thanks

Comment: There is a lack of lot of information. What is your OS? WIndows/Linux? Did you try tnsping? How are you connecting to the DB? Locally or remotely?

Comment: It is Windows 8.1 Pro  (X64) .. Yes I tried tnsping and I'm connecting to BD through SQL plus locally

Comment: Go to `services.msc`, and find the Oracle service. See whether the status is `started` or not?

Comment: Lalit Kumar .. That's the weird this I stated! I don't have OracleService in the services.msc

Comment: Then you don't have Oracle installed.

Comment: You mean not installed properly, since I have the listener , recovery services , ... how can I add it?

Comment: Did you only install the software or also created an instance? Use `DBCA` to first create the database. My guess is you have only installed the Oracle software and yet to create an instance.

Comment: what do you mean by creating an instance ? you mean my own database?

Comment: While installing, the installer would have asked you few options, install software only, or create and configure database. Depends which option you chose.

Comment: I choose Create and configure a DB

Answer (score 0):

Please check your oracle service and listener are started. Oracle service name usual like `OracleService<your sid>`. 
For example.
your Oracle SID is `orcl`. Your Orace service name is `OracleServiceORCL`.
and your Listener should end with `"TNSListener"` like default listener name `OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener`. The both of them have to running.
Then, try to connect your DB with SQLPlus. Open DOS command promt and type this command

```
>sqlplus <your userlogin>/<your login password>@<your sid>
```

If connection is success. Result should show like below massage.

```
C:\Users\monkawee>sqlplus ***/******@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on ﾈ. 狠.ﾂ. 3 17:04:57 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


爼ﾗ靉ﾁｵ靉｡ﾑｺ:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hello. 
as I mentioned, I don't have OracleService in services. I guess that's why It's not working but I don't know how to get it!

Comment: Are you install without creating any database?